# CMS Made Simple mail function broken after update to 1.11.9

Tags: php, content-management-system, phpmailer, formbuilder

I recently updated two websites of mine from CMS Made Simple 1.8.2 to 1.11.9 and from 1.11.5 to 1.11.9. On both sites the e-mail functionality is completely broken. With the module FormBuilder I now get an error after submitting:

`"Could not instantiate mail function"`

I don't understand why, because it was working correctly before. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Do you have any logs, or anything that can point to the error?

Comment: Sadly no, this is one of the weaknesses I think. I'm totally in the dark here.